# Check if certificate is wildcard certificate

Tags: certificate, x509certificate

We have a website and we'd like to check if the certificate installed is a wild-card certificate or tied to the specific URL only. Could this be checked in an easy way?

Answer (score 21):

Browse to a secured page on your server, ie: https://yoursite.com

Click on the padlock in the URL bar and view the certificate.  To do this in Chrome you click on the `Connection` tab then `Certificate Information`.

Check that the `Common Name (CN)` contains a * in front of your domain name.

Eg. for https://www.google.com

[image: *.google.com cert]

Comment: This is answer is a little inaccurate, or rather; incomplete. The `Common Name` for a wildcard certificate does *not* need to start with an asterisk (e.g., it can be instead listed simply as "example.com"). In that case a header named `Extensions` should be shown below `Fingerprints` containing an item called [Certificate Subject Alternative Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) with domain values including the wildcard "*.example.com" value.

Comment: This comment was very helpful, should have been an answer.

Answer (score 10):

This can be done by checking for the common name in the SSL's subject.  You can use the bash command `openssl` on *NIX clients.

For instance, google.com and www.google.com use two different SSLs.  The first is a wildcard, the second is domain specific.

```
$ echo | openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -subject | grep -o "CN=.*" | cut -c 4-
*.google.com
$ echo | openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -subject | grep -o "CN=.*" | cut -c 4-
www.google.com
```

Comment: No longer working on Mac. It says `invalid2.invalid`

Answer (score 4):

You could look up the cert at its issuer-- you should be able to see there whether it's issued to *.domain.com or www.domain.com.  Eg, [Verisign](https://securitycenter.verisign.com/celp/enroll/outsideSearch?application_locale=VRSN_US).

Comment: Any idea if GoDaddy has a similar kind of search?

Comment: If " *.domain.com " then wildcard and if "www.domain.com" or "pay.domain.com" then domain specific !

Answer (score 2):

Similar to other online tools for web purposes, I found this handy too, quite simple replace your hostname with your https siteurl it will explain what problem you are going through, and what solutions can benefit you...

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname={siteurl}

Comment: It is simple easy to understand and precise. Thank you @justnajm!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can use free online tools like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest. Besides the domain info, they will also tell you other important detail about your certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Using command line openssl client, this can be checked as follows, on all UNIX like systems:

```
SERVERNAME=google.com; echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect $SERVERNAME:443 -servername $SERVERNAME 2>/dev/null| grep subject | grep -o "CN=.*"
```

This is an improvement over the Steve Robbins answer above.